# How do i apply a patch to Synergy in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, patch

I have downloaded a patch for a keyboard problem in Synergy for my mac but have no idea how to use it

Comment: "Patch" can mean many things. Please link to the patch so you can get a qualified answer.

Comment: the patch is from this page http://synergy-foss.org/pm/issues/57

Comment: I see there's already a patched version of the server: 

`synergys-patched - synergys patched with synergy_57_corrected.patch (5.5 MB) Matthew Toso, 03/24/2011 06:21 pm`.  Have you tried that?

Comment: I have already downloaded that but this is not a usable file format, in fact there is no file format that I can see

Answer (score 1):

The parched version synergys-patched is a binary and thus should replace the executable file synergys. You will have to rename it and copy it t the correct place.

However as the bug seems to be 2 years old and the fix is due 11th April I would wait for the next release.

Comment: The correct place likely being the folder Contents/MacOS/ within the Synergy bundle. Right-click and Show Package Contents to access.